# Switch view with same object in winUI3

Tags: winui-3, winui

Example I have 4 images, I want to make a button to switch view for displaying those images:
view1(view1.xaml) as uniform grid(2x2), view2(view2.xaml) as listview(1x4), and 2 views use the same datatemplate (Image).

What is the best way to do it?

I will re-create object (images) and view or I can keep the same object, view instanse when switch view?

Should I put the datatemplate in resourceDictionary and 2 views will refer it?

I very appreciate if have any code example for it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```xml
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem Header="2x2">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" RowDefinitions="*,*">
            <Image
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Source="/Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
            <Image
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Source="/Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
            <Image
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Source="/Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
            <Image
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Source="/Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
        </Grid>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="1x4">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*">
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="/Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="/Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
            <Image Grid.Column="3" Source="/Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
        </Grid>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```